# Python find value of view state given source

Tags: python, regex, string, viewstate

I am trying to write a program to decode view state given a url. I know similar programs exist but this is more of an excursive than a project.
Given the html source of a page, how can I get the value of the view state form element.
I started by  doing this:

```
def get_viewstate(html):
        i = html.index('id="__VIEWSTATE" value="')
        somedata = html[i+len('id="__VIEWSTATE" value="'):]
```

But I couldn't figure out an *efficient* way to only retrieve the value of the element up to the end tag.
What is the most efficient way to retrieve the value of this form element?

Comment: The best way to do it would be to parse the HTML.

Comment: The "most efficient way" in term of performance is clearly the way you use. However, you can replace `len('id="__VIEWSTATE" value="')` by its value, since it is a fixed length string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de) with css selector:

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
matched = root.cssselect('#__VIEWSTATE')
if matched:
    value = matched[0].get('value')
```

Using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
matched = soup.select('#__VIEWSTATE')
if matched:
    value = matched[0].get('value')
```

Comment: Is the '#' necessary?

Comment: @735Tesla, Yes, it is necessary. `#__VIEWSTATE` is css selector. (which is equivalent to `*[id="__VIEWSTATE"]`).